# Prove an identity involving factorials inside summations

Tags: summation, factorial, products

Prove that: 
\begin{align*}\sum _{k=0}^N\left(k\cdot \frac{N!}{k!\left(N-k\right)!}\cdot \frac{\left(X+k-1\right)!}{\left(X-1\right)!}\cdot \frac{\left(L-X+N-k-1\right)!}{\left(L-X-1\right)!}\frac{\left(L-1\right)!}{\left(L+N-1\right)!}\right)&= \frac{XN}{L}
\end{align*}

for $[0<X<L]\in \mathbb{N}$

My attempt using induction: (I'll leave out the verification of the base cases, but they do hold). Factoring the non-iterates out and moving them to the other side of the equality of the induction hypothesis:

\begin{align*}
\frac{N!}{\left(X-1\right)!\left(L-X-1\right)!}\sum _{k=0}^N\frac{k}{k!\left(N-k\right)!}\cdot \left(X+k-1\right)!\cdot \left(L-X+N-k-1\right)!&=\frac{XN}{L!}\left(N+L-1\right)!
\end{align*}

From the domain of $X$ and $L, \quad X-1 \geq 0$ and $L-X-1 \geq 0$. The $(X+k-1)!$ term can be written as $(k+X-1)(k+X-2)...(k+1)k!$ -- similarly, the $\left(L-X+N-k-1\right)!$ term is expressible as $(N-k+L-X-1)(N-k+L-X-2)...(N-k+1)(N-k)!$ We can cancel the factorial terms in the denominator of the first term of the summation and express the rising factorials using product notation. This returns the induction hypothesis that will be used.

\begin{align*}
\frac{N!}{(X-1)!(L-X-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^N\left(k\prod_{i=1}^{X-1}(k+i)\prod_{i=1}^{L-X-1}(N-k+i)\right) &= \frac{XN}{L!}\left(N+L-1\right)!
\end{align*}

Inductive step:

First we note the required form: $\frac{X(N+1)}{L!}(L+N)!$.

Through some algebraic manipulation, we arrive at the following.

\begin{align*}
&(N+1)\left(\frac{N!}{(X-1)!(L-X-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{N}\left(k\prod_{i=1}^{X-1}(k+i)\prod_{i=1}^{L-X-1}(N+1-k+i)\right)+\frac{(X+N)!}{(X-1)!}\right)
\end{align*}

Because of the $N+1$ nested in the second product of the summation, there does not seem to be a way to insert the induction hypothesis. If one eliminates the $+1$ via altering the limits of the product, a new $k$ term appears:

Inductive step:
\begin{align*}
&(N+1)\left(\frac{N!}{(X-1)!(L-X-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{N}\left(k\prod_{i=1}^{X-1}(k+i)\prod_{i=2}^{L-X}(N-k+i)\right)+\frac{(X+N)!}{(X-1)!}\right)
\end{align*}

Compared to the induction hypothesis:
\begin{align*}
\frac{N!}{\left(X-1\right)!\left(L-X-1\right)!}\left(\sum _{k=0}^N\left(k\left(\prod _{i=1}^{X-1}\left(k+i\right)\right)\left(\prod _{i=2}^{L-X}\left(N-k+i\right)\right)\left(\frac{\left(N-k+1\right)}{N-k+L-X}\right)\right)\right)
\end{align*}

Is there any way to resolve this, or is a proof by induction not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach without using induction. We start with the left-hand side, do some simplifications to finally obtain the right-hand side.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum _{k=0}^N& k\cdot \frac{N!}{k!\left(N-k\right)!}\cdot \frac{\left(X+k-1\right)!}{\left(X-1\right)!}\cdot \frac{\left(L-X+N-k-1\right)!}{\left(L-X-1\right)!}\frac{\left(L-1\right)!}{\left(L+N-1\right)!}\\
> &=\frac{N!(L-1)!}{(L+N-1)!}\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{(X+k-1)!}{(k-1)!(X-1)!}\cdot\frac{(L-X+N-k-1)!}{(N-k)!(L-X-1)!}\tag{1}\\
> &=\binom{L+N-1}{N}^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^N X\binom{X+k-1}{k-1}\binom{L-X+N-k-1}{N-k}\tag{2}\\
> &=X\binom{L+N-1}{N}^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\binom{X+k}{k}\binom{L-X+N-k-2}{N-k-1}\tag{3}\\
> &=X\binom{L+N-1}{N}^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\binom{-X-1}{k}(-1)^k\binom{-L+X}{N-1-k}(-1)^{N-1-k}\tag{4}\\
> &=(-1)^{N-1}X\binom{L+N-1}{N}^{-1}\binom{-L-1}{N-1}\tag{5}\\
> &=X\binom{L+N-1}{N}^{-1}\binom{L+N-1}{N-1}\tag{6}\\
> &=\frac{XN}{L}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we do some rearrangements, factor out terms independent of the index variable $k$ and start with index $k=1$ since the left-hand expression contains the factor $k=0$.
- In (2) we rewrite the expression using binomial coefficients.
- In (3) we shift the index by one to start with $k=0$.
- In (4) we use the rule $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (5) we apply *[Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity)*.
- In (6) we apply again the rule from (4).

> *Note:* A proof by induction is also possible. But, if a direct transformation is within reach, this often provides more insight. The main aspect here which connects the left-hand side and the right-hand side is an application of Vandermonde's identity. We would probably  not see this, when proving the identity using induction.

Comment: Applying ${{-p} \choose q}={{p+q-1} \choose q}(-1)^q$ seems to be the crux of the proof for me. The (Chu)-Vandermonde identity was actually the first on the list of identities of summations of products of binomial coefficients at https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Summations_of_Products_of_Binomial_Coefficients , though I thought it wouldn't be applicable because the upper terms of the binomial coefficient weren't constants. I tried manipulating the last identity on the page (in the comments to the other answer) and failed.

Comment: I turned to induction as a brute force proof because I have seen another proof of an equivalent expression to the one I posted, though the statement was proven using probability instead.

Comment: @user1239334: I see. I've pointed to Vandermonde since it is the key to collapse the sum. But, you're right, both aspects are vital to solve the problem this way. Good to see your different approaches. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It is better to simplify the summation at first:
$$\begin{align*}k\cdot \frac{N!}{k!\left(N-k\right)!}\cdot \frac{\left(X+k-1\right)!}{\left(X-1\right)!}\cdot \frac{\left(L-X+N-k-1\right)!}{\left(L-X-1\right)!}\frac{\left(L-1\right)!}{\left(L+N-1\right)!}\\
=k {N\choose k}k!{{X+k-1}\choose k}(N-k)!{{L-X+N-k-1}\choose {N-k}}\frac 1{N!}{{L+N-1}\choose N}^{-1}
\\=k{{X+k-1}\choose k}{{L-X+N-k-1}\choose {N-k}}{{L+N-1}\choose N}^{-1}
\end{align*}$$
Then it boils down to:
$${{L+N-1}\choose N}^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^N k{{X+k-1}\choose k}{{L-X+N-k-1}\choose {N-k}}=\frac{XN}L$$
So you need to prove
$$\sum_{k=1}^N \frac kX{{X+k-1}\choose k}{{L-X+N-k-1}\choose {N-k}}=\frac NL{{L+N-1}\choose{N}}$$
Note that $\frac NL{{L+N-1}\choose{N}}={{L+N-1}\choose{L}}$ and $\frac kX{{X+k-1}\choose k}={{X+k-1}\choose X}$. It is clear that the above identity holds for $N=1$, i.e.
$$\sum_{k=1}^1 {{X+k-1}\choose X}{{L-X-k}\choose {1-k}}={{L}\choose{L}}=1$$
Assume the identity holds for $N=n$,
$$\sum_{k=1}^n {{X+k-1}\choose X}{{L-X+n-k-1}\choose {n-k}}={{L+n-1}\choose{L}}$$
therefore
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} {{X+k-2}\choose X}{{L-X+n-k}\choose {n-k+1}}={{L+n-1}\choose{L}}\tag{*}\label{*}$$
You need to prove it for $N=n+1$:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} {{X+k-1}\choose X}{{L-X+n-k}\choose {n-k+1}}={{L+n}\choose{L}}\tag{p}\label{p}$$
The left side of $\eqref{p}$ can be written as:
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} {{X+k-2}\choose X}{{L-X+n-k}\choose {n-k+1}}+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} {{X+k-2}\choose {X-1}}{{L-X+n-k}\choose {n-k+1}}&\stackrel{\eqref{*}}=\\
{{L+n-1}\choose{L}}+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} {{X+k-2}\choose {X-1}}{{L-X+n-k}\choose {n-k+1}}
\end{align}$$
And since
$${{L+n}\choose{L}}-{{L+n-1}\choose{L}}={{L+n-1}\choose{L-1}}$$
it is sufficient to prove the following based on $\eqref{*}$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} {{X+k-2}\choose {X-1}}{{L-X+n-k}\choose {n-k+1}}={{L+n-1}\choose{L-1}}\\=\frac Ln{{L+n-1}\choose{L}}\tag{q}\label{q}$$
But it is hard to get a relationship between $\eqref{q}$ and $\eqref{*}$ and I can't go any further `:/`

Comment: Still having trouble with the $N+1$ terms in the second binomial when I try induction. Applying Pascal's rule and substituting the induction hypothesis where possible, I get $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(k\left(\frac{L-X-1}{N-K+1}\right){{X+k-1} \choose k}{{L-X+N-k-1} \choose {N-k}}\right) + X{{L+N-1} \choose {N-1}} + X {{X+N} \choose N}$.

Comment: Looking at the last identity on this page as it seems to resemble the conjecture: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Summations_of_Products_of_Binomial_Coefficients -- and letting $r= X$, $s = L-X-1$ and $t = -1$, I can express the conjecture in the following form: $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(k \frac{r}{r+k}{{r+k} \choose k}{{s+n-k} \choose {n-k}}\right)$. The right hand side when expressed in this form is $\frac{nr}{r+s}{{r+s+n} \choose n}$, but the k inside the summation stops me from forming an equality.

Comment: @user1239334 I'll post a complete answer. Please give me some time because I am at work right now!

Comment: I can rearrange to get $\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac{X}{k-1}{{X+k-2} \choose {X}} {{L-X+n-k} \choose {n-k +1}}$, but I don't see how I can manipulate the $\frac{X}{k-1}$ inside the summation to equal $\frac{n}{L}$ based on $\eqref{*}$

Comment: @user1239334 Sorry, it looks like a dead-end. You can un-accept my answer for now `-_-`